# How should I consume a WCF service using MVC3

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, rest

I am writing a fairly simple MVC3 application that allows a user to retrieve and modify some configuration data held by a WCF service. The configuration data will not change very often but needs to be maintainable by the user.
Once the user is happy with the configuration, they will launch some processing from the UI or by the scheduled execution of a VB script.

I'm fairly new to WCF and even newer to MVC3 but I'd like to make all the comms to and from the service RESTful. Is this a good thing to do?

I'd been planning to perform the service communications from the MVC controller. This would make a  HTTP Get request to retrieve the current configuration and a HTTP Post to apply the modified configuration. I'd also use a Get request to launch the processing.

Could anyone provide an example (or point me in the direction) of how I should be doing this?

Comment: Are you owner of web service?

Comment: Yes. I've written the web service to do all the processing. The UI is only required to apply configuration and launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer I've found was [here:](http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/archive/2008/10/08/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services.aspx), using the channel factory.

I still don't know if it's the best way but it left my code looking clean enough. Below is a sample from my controller.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SettingsModel config = null;

        // Set up a channel factory to use the webHTTPBinding
        using (WebChannelFactory<IChangeService> serviceChannel = 
            new WebChannelFactory<IChangeService>(new Uri(baseServiceUrl )))
        {
            IChangeService channel = serviceChannel.CreateChannel();
            config = channel.GetSysConfig();
        }

        ViewBag.Message = "Service Configuration";

        return View(config);
    }
```

Comment: For the above code the client needs to have the interface during the development and changes to the interface needs the client code to recompile as well.

Comment: @Rajesh, I have the interface and the data contract for the model in a class library. This project is shared between the UI and the service. I didn't want to include the service in the UI project, which would make it too closely bound.

Comment: Trying to get this to work on my project. When I call the service (channel.GetSysConfig()) I get an error 404.
What is the baseServiceUrl I need to use and how to determine it?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below links for some sample code to build a RESTful WCF Service and the how the client would access the service.

Link to create a RESTful service: [here](http://rajeshsv.blogspot.com/2011/11/building-rest-service-using-wcf.html)

Link to create a .NET client that consumes the RESTful service : [here](http://rajeshsv.blogspot.com/2011/11/net-client-to-invoke-rest-service.html)

Hope the information helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the owner of web service, you can directly reference implementation of service in your mvc project and use it without web reference. You can write some like this:

```
// example of ws
public class Service1 : IService1
 {
        public string GetData( int value )
        {
            return string.Format( "You entered: {0}", value );
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract( CompositeType composite )
        {
            if( composite == null )
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException( "composite" );
            }
            if( composite.BoolValue )
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
 }

// example of mvc action
public class HomeController : Controller
 {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IService1 service = new Service1();

            service.GetDataUsingDataContract(....)

            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }
 }
```

Comment: If I use a service reference, doesn't that use SOAP? Isn't REST the way forward with MVC3 as it's stateless?

Comment: Each call to ws are stateless and each call to mvc are stateless. I have updated the answer with an example for help.

Comment: I've tried the code you suggested and I'm getting an empty data contract object back. I think this is because I have yet to define the end points in the service and UI.